# Bibliography not showing at end of document

Tags: biblatex

Following various examples, here here my current (relevant) code:

in %Preamble%

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Pages/bibliography.bib}
```

And at the vary end of the document:
\nocite{*}
\chapter{Bibliography}
\printbibliography %Prints bibliography

Bibliography is not showing, what am I missing or doing wrong?

---

I trimmed down and anonimsed the code for testing, still not working:

File `main.tex`

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[a4paper,french,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Pages/bibliography.bib}


\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \input{Pages/xx-Bibliography.tex}   
    
\end{document}
```

File `xx-Bibliography.tex`

```
\chapter{Bibliography}
\printbibliography %Prints bibliography
```

or

```
\chapter{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
```

File `Pages/bibliography.bib` : sample found on https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

---

Also tried `Pages/xx-Bibliography.tex`:

```
\chapter{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[keyword={physics},heading=none,resetnumbers=true]
```

Comment: You must cite something, with e.g \cite or \nocite.

Comment: Thank you. So I added \nocite{*} in the main document (will edit post). Still not showing.

Comment: If you want to see the bibliography whether you cite or not, you may want to use `\nocite{*}` command just after the `\begin{document}`. If you also want to see specific reference documents without citing you may use `\nocite{}` like this: `\nocite{<your-key-word>}`.

Comment: Did you run biber? (biber is not bibtex!)

Comment: What is biber and how does it work?

Comment: You may need to update your package definition like this: `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}`.

Comment: Package definition updated ad shown, still nothing showing.

Comment: My last suggestion is to use `\printbibliography` like this: `\printbibliography[keyword={<your-key-word>},heading=none,resetnumbers=true]`. Because with all these configuration I have a working copy..

Comment: What is <your-key-word> ?

Comment: If I were you, @UlrikeFischer has been destroyed me already..

Comment: Tried this, still nothing showing: `\printbibliography[keyword={physics},heading=none,resetnumbers=true]`

Comment: Biber is an application that you must run between two pdflatex compilations. It will extract and preprocess the bib entries so that biblatex can use them. Search the sites, there are answers how to use biber with your editor.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains what Biber does (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 can help clear some confusion about the different terms involved). https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains how you get your editor to run Biber for you.

Comment: Try a simple `\printbibliography` first before you worry about advanced stuff like `\printbibliography[keyword={physics},heading=none,resetnumbers=true]`. Unrelated to your problem, but you shouldn't need to `\chapter{Bibliography}` before `\printbibliography`. `biblatex` automatically typesets an appropriate bibliography heading.